# Render only a portion of PDF file using ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

Tags: php, angular, typescript, laravel, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

I'm making an app using Laravel 10 & Angular 16, and I want to show only a part of a PDF file, similar to websites like [scribd.com](https://scribd.com)

Is it possible to render only part of a PDF file (limited number of pages) using `<ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>`?

Here's what I have in my component's HTML file:

```
<ngx-extended-pdf-viewer [src]="fileURL"></ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>
```

Where fileURL is a Blob object retrieved from a backend API response.

```
...
showPDF(book_id: number) {
  this.bookService.showPDF(book_id).subscribe({
    next: (blob) => {
      const file = new Blob([blob], { type: 'application/pdf' });
      this.fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    },
    error: console.log,
  })
}
...
```

Here's the service

```
...
showPDF(book_id: number): Observable<any> {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
    }),
    responseType: 'blob' as 'json',
  };
  return this.http.get<any>(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/book/${book_id}/show-pdf`, httpOptions);
}
...
```

I'm able to render the full PDF file, but that's not quite what I'm looking for.